# unable to save a model object when associations are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, model-associations

In my rails application, i'm unable to save the model object when associations are present.
I'm using mongo as db.
 Brief explanation:

I have a model object,

```
@obj1 = User.create(name: "name1")
```

When i do @obj1.save, it works fine. Now i added a relationship say,

```
has_many :offices
```

and then i try to save the same object with new entry.

```
@obj1 = User.create(name: "name2")
```

I get a error like

```
 /gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
 gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
```

Edit:

Full error trace:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Office
            from /home/workspace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@cv_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
            from /home/workspace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@cv_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
            from /home/workspace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@cv_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
            from /home/workspace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@cv_app/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message? You've only posted part of the trace (where it originated from) not the actual error.

Comment: Is there an `Office` class to associate with? The error suggests that it is looking for the other end of that association and not finding any class to associate with.

Comment: @Shadwell there is an office class for sure, but still i should be able to make an independent User entry to db..

Answer (score 0):

In your user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offices 
end
```

In your office model

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, try this

```
@user = User.new
@user.name = "xyz"
@user.save
```

for relationship

```
@user = User.offices.build
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the office model and table has created or not. It these two were created it won't give this kind of error.

Comment: ...i'm using mongo so no tables